# What IDE should I use for experimenting with the Chromium source code

Tags: c++, google-chrome, ide, ubuntu, chromium

According to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxEclipseDev
"Developing Chrome with Eclipse/CDT is fairly unpolished."

Which IDE would be *polished* and provide a more favourable experience?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: The one you are used to. An IDE is targeted to all source codes and not to a specific one, so just pick up the one you know the best.

Comment: I'm used to Eclipse and I don't have the time to start testing all them IDEs. This is why I'm asking this.

Comment: Then keep going with Eclipse, tbh your question doesn't make sense at all. You'll be more productive using an IDE you know well rather than an IDE you don't know but is "polished" since you say you don't have time to test a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Monodevelop. As far as I know, it supports Visual Studio projects which can be generated by the Chromium build system.

Comment: This is not relevant to the user's OS (Ubuntu). It's not even remotely possible to build through Visual Studio project files on Linux.

Comment: @ruben, entity is correct.  Monodevelop [can open](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#Can_I_import_my_Visual_Studio_2K5.2b_project_into_MonoDevelop.3f), and I believe build from, (some) Visual Studio projects.

Comment: Matthew: it would be awesome if it could open (Visual) C++ projects, but I thought Mono was .Net/C# oriented...